# Fluid and dynamic animation on object appear and disappear (HTML/JS/CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

it's difficult to describe in the title,but what I'm thinking of are those sites like some of the Tumblrs or some other fancy webpages where the parts (for example the images) when they appear they move in next to the existing ones, you can move them and all the others move along and rearrange themselves. Same when some of the middle disappear and all the others rearrange and move into the space of the one that disappeard.
My question is : how to do that? is there a plugin for that? if not, what would be the code for that ? I presume it's not that easy...
An example would be : 
I have some images          (1)--(2)--(3)--(4)
I check a box that make the (2) disappear and the 3 and 4 move along  (1)--<-(3)-<-(4)

And by "move" I don't mean "appear/disappear" but litteraly animate the position, fade in/out and this should apply to any divs on multiple lines or anything!

Thank's for your help in advance

Comment: You can use css transformation on the visibilty http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp

Answer (score 0):

possibly you could adapt jquery [sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) to your needs ?

Comment: well sort of, I really think about something like this http://asimove.com/showcase/

Answer (score 0):

I think I found exactly what you are looking for [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-removing-replacing-moving-elements/)!.

The author has explained how to go about what you require in quite some detail with examples and a near walk-through using jQuery.

In order to move content as you've described - (1)--<-(3)-<-(4), you can 'cheat' by inheriting the CSS styling of the containers from 2-3 and 3-4 respectively so it seems 2 has been removed and 3, 4 have moved to take its place without using elaborate JS.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be the answer !
http://masonry.desandro.com/#getting-started